# Difference between while and if when using getline()

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, getline

I have a .cpp file that reads from two .txt files and outputs them on the screen.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class check
{
public:
    void display();
    ifstream read_number, read_amount;
};

void check::display()
{
    read_number.open("number.txt");
    read_amount.open("amount.txt");
    if (read_number.is_open() && read_amount.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        bool transfer = false;
        while (getline(read_number, line) && transfer == false)
        {
            cout << line << "\t";
            transfer = true;
            if (getline(read_amount, line) && transfer == true)
            {
                cout << "$" << line << endl;
                transfer = false;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open one of the two files." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    check obj;
    obj.display();

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the "transfer" bool variable as a way to read one line from a file and then another line from a second file.
The first .txt file just has these numbers and nothing else:

```
03
32
26
```

The second .txt file has these numbers:

```
50.30
15.26
20.36
```

The above code works as intended. It produces the following result when run:

```
03    $50.30 // first value is from file 1, second value from file 2.
32    $15.26
26    $20.36
```

However, my question is, **why does the following change causes the last value (20.36) to be omitted from the output?**

Changed:

```
while (getline(read_amount, line) && transfer == true)
{
    cout << "$" << line << endl;
    transfer = false;
}
```

The output resulting from the change:

```
03    $50.30 // first value is from file 1, second value from file 2.
32    $15.26
26
```

Please let me know if you guys need any clarification on my question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: _"Please let me know if you guys need any clarification"_ Yes, we need a [mcve], that's a  requirement when asking here.

Comment: Unrelated: `if (read_number.is_open() && read_amount.is_open())` can be written as `if(read_number && read_amount)`

Comment: Fyi, `while (transfer && getline(read_amount, line))` will return the behavior you expected.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I apologize, here is the reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks for all your feed back, Ted and Craig!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while` is a loop statement, so the execution is looped.

Let's see what will happen step-by-step:

```
transfer = true; // (1)
while (getline(read_amount, line) && transfer == true) // (2)
{
    cout << "$" << line << endl; // (3)
    transfer = false; // (4)
}
```

1. `transfer` is set to `true` at line (1)
2. Something is read to `line` at line (2)
3. Go inside the loop because `transfer` is `true` at line (2)
4. Something is printed at line (3)
5. `transfer` is set to `false` at line (4)
6. Something is read to `line` at line (2)
7. Break from the loop because `transfer` is `false` at line (2)

Among this step, reading is done twice and it will consume something from the input.
On the other hand, using `if`, execution is not looped and reading is done only once.
This will make the difference.